# Multiple similar values of a dictionary in an array changes when one of the values is modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

Let's say I'm performing some operation on an array as follows:

```
>>arr = np.array([1,2,34,567,433243,787,832])
>>h = np.where(arr < 100, {'hello' : 1}, {'hi' : 2 })
array([{'hello': 1}, {'hello': 1}, {'hello': 1}, {'hi': 2}, {'hi': 2},{'hi': 2}, {'hi': 2}], dtype=object)
```

When I try to add a key-value pair at some selective indices, It gets replicated across all the indices and gives me something like this:

```
>>h[0]['hola']=12
>>h[4]['heyy']=11
>>h
array([{'hello': 1, 'hola': 12}, {'hello': 1, 'hola': 12},{'hello': 1, 'hola': 12}, {'hi': 2, 'heyy': 11},{'hi': 2, 'heyy': 11}, {'hi': 2, 'heyy': 11},{'hi': 2, 'heyy': 11}], dtype=object)
```

While I expect the values to change only at those specific indices(0 & 4) and get something like this:

```
array([{'hello': 1, 'hola': 12}, {'hello': 1}, {'hello': 1}, {'hi': 2}, {'hi': 2, 'heyy': 11}, {'hi': 2,}, {'hi': 2}], dtype=object)
```

How do I obtain the desired output?.Thanks in advance

Comment: you create two dict items and then have severarl copies of them. So changing one will change all copys. you can see this if you do `[id(d) for d in h]` to print the id of each dict in your array `[72361176, 72361176, 72361176, 75001400, 75001400, 75001400, 75001400]` you can see the first 3 dicts are all actually the same dict, and the last 4 are all the same dict

Comment: Okay got it. But how do I make them point to different memory locations so that they are treated unique

Comment: Do you need to use numpy.where? you could achieve the same result with list comprehension `h = np.array([{'hello': 1} if i < 100 else {'hi': 2} for i in arr])`

Comment: Ohhh yeah..Thank you so much @ChrisDoyle

Comment: I don't think making an array out of that list of dicts has any advantages.  You have to iterate to do anything, and list iteration is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing 3 args to np.where a condition an expression if its true and and expression if its false. These expressions are evaluated before being passed to the where method. Such that the dicts are created once for true and once for false then the same dict will be used whenever that Boolean value occurs in the expression.

Instaed you can just use a list comprehension to achieve what you want.

`h = np.array([{'hello': 1} if i < 100 else {'hi': 2} for i in arr])`